# How to use Find Scope in Synopsys Verdi

Tags: verilog, synopsys-vcs

The "Find Scope..." option in Synopsys Verdi doesn't seem to be able to find anything other than top level modules.  I have the Scope Type set to Module and I have tried a bunch of different variations:

```
1) the module name with the * wildcard before and/or after: this will find top level modules no problem, but not anything lower.
2) The path to the module separated by .
3) The path to the module separated by /
4) Variations 2 & 3 with the * wildcard.
```

There must be something simple I am missing, but what is it?

Comment: I use this to load waveforms from a previous simulation:   verdi -dbdir simv.daidir -ssf verilog.fsdb

Comment: When I run `vcs` with the `-kdb`, then I run your `verdi` command, `Find Scope` works for me.  Try it with the small example in my Answer.  What version of Verdi and VCS do you use?  I'm on 2019.06.

Answer (score 1):

By default, *Verdi* treats modules compiled using `-y` as "library" modules, and they are not visible in the *nTrace* GUI.

The solution is to use the `verdi -ssy` command line option to gain visibility into the library modules.

---

Consider this scenario.  I have 3 Verilog files:

1. tb.v
2. lib/foo.v
3. lib/bar.v

If I launch Verdi with the following command, it will compile cleanly, but the submodules (`foo` and `bar`) will not be visible in the GUI.  Only the top-level modules are visible:

```
verdi tb.v -y lib +libext+.v
```

To gain visibility, add the `-ssy` option:

```
verdi tb.v -y lib +libext+.v -ssy
```

I can see all modules in the hierarchy.

---

**tb.v:**

```
module tb;
    foo i0 ();
    foo i1 ();
    foo i2 ();
endmodule

module tb2;
endmodule
```

**foo.v:**

```
module foo;
   bar b0 ();
   bar b1 ();
endmodule
```

**bar.v:**

```
module bar;
endmodule
```